# Silverlight 3 Datagrid - Temporarily highlight a row

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm using the Silverlight 3 datagrid and have a number of custom styles applied - for example, a row style with TargetType data:DataGridRow. However, being very new to Silverlight I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve the following effect: highlight a row (temporarily, say for 2 seconds) when some property of the data item for that row changes.

I can iterate the row components on item update using code similar to the following:

```
foreach (Object p in CollectionView.View)
{
    TextBlock block = (TextBlock)Grid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(p);
    if (block != null && block.DataContext == recentlyUpdatedObject)
    {
        // effect rows visual state here
    }
}
```

So my main requirement is to apply the temporary highlight somehow to the row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

fturtle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook into some event as in this [silverlight row color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509714/c-silverlight-datagrid-row-color-change) post.

and then set off a timer and change the rows color back.

Still that seems a bit clunky.