# Change the Background Color of Entire Column of WPF DataGrid at RunTime

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, colors

All, I am relatively new to WPF. I have searched around for the answer to this, but all I have found is how to do colorise rows at run-time not columns; for example the following questions:

1. [Change WPF Datagrid Row Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056657/change-wpf-datagrid-row-color)
2. [How do I programatically change datagrid row color in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030361/how-do-i-programatically-change-datagrid-row-color-in-wpf)
3. [Programmatically assigning a color to a row in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847359/wpf-programmatically-assigning-a-color-to-a-row-in-datagrid)
4. [Change DataGrid cell colour based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values)

et al.

I have seen the `CellStyle` property on the [MSDN DataGrid pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn.aspx) but its use is not obvious to me at all despite searches around this as well.

**how to change the background colour of an entire column at runtime?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The only way I got it to work is by setting the columns by myself, (by not using AutoGenerate).  So first thing to do is define the columns:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Frid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Then you need to set each column CellStyle and bind the Background to a static resource that you can declare at Window.Resources:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" ...>
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="clBr" Color="White" />
</Window.Resources>
...
```

Columns:

```
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" 
                                Value="{StaticResource clBr}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

then you can just manipulate the static resource by either code or xaml manipulation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I want to know how to do this at run-time as the columns I have are variable and created at run-time. All the best...

Comment: i want it to be done at run time . i am binding datagrid with datatable on window load.so how can it be done?

Comment: I did what you indicated in your answer, it worked. but how can I change it programatically during runtime?

Comment: Runtime changes would require DynamicResource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-overview

Answer (score 22):

A bit old, but here is how you can do this programmatically (for AutoGen columns):

```
private void dgvMailingList_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
    e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty,  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)));
}
```

The same approach can be applied to non-AutoGen columns too.