# Change datagrid column background using column name

Tags: wpf, datagrid, background

What i want to do is change the whole background of a column using triggers and the specific column name.
Something like, change all column background to yellow if column name is "X". My column is auto generated. Can it be done? Thx for help!

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,46,0,6" Name="dgvPrev" Width="Auto" MinWidth="700">
```

**C#**

-create column header

```
        textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        textColumn.Header = "Main Id";
        textColumn.Foreground = Brushes.DarkOrange;
        textColumn.FontWeight = FontWeights.DemiBold;
        textColumn.Binding = new Binding("MainId");
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```

-add data to it

```
    for (int k = 0; k < GridCollectionAllNext.Count; k++)
    {
        //New anonymous object
        dynamic row = new ExpandoObject();
        ((IDictionary<String, Object>)row)["MainId"] = GridCollectionAllPrev[k].ItemMain.Id;
    }
```

In the code above i managed to get the rows in the column colour orange.. but i want the background of the cells in that column to be orange.

Comment: any specific reason to not to use column generating event ?

Comment: I have tried: private void dgvAll_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e){  e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange)));} .. but is not triggered. Don't know why

Comment: add code to your question

Comment: So you have set the "AutoGeneratingColumn" event handler also in the XAML of the datagrid? The solution with this event seemed to work for this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21670347/4424024

Comment: I did.That's exactly the code that i have tried but is not working. It may be the way that i create columns in code behind, i suppose :D